# Schwarz Function of an Ellipse

Tags: complex-analysis, conic-sections, contour-integration

I want to find the Schwarz function of the ellipse define by
$$
\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1, \quad a > b > 0.
$$
To do so, substitute
$$
x = \frac{z+\bar{z}}{2}, \quad y = \frac{z - \bar{z}}{2i}
$$
into the ellipse equation and solve for $\bar{z}$. With $c:c^2 = a^2 - b^2$ being the focal distance of the ellipse, one obtains
$$
\bar{z} = \frac{(a^2+b^2)z \pm 2ab\sqrt{z^2-c^2}}{c^2}.
$$
Now at this point, a few texts I have read discard the positive root solution and define the Schwarz function of the ellipse as
$$
S(z) = \frac{(a^2+b^2)z - 2ab\sqrt{z^2-c^2}}{c^2}
$$
and then use this to evaluate line integrals along the ellipse:
$$
\oint_{\partial \Omega} \frac{\bar{z}}{z-\zeta}\, d\zeta = \oint_{\partial \Omega} \frac{S(z)}{z-\zeta}\, d\zeta.
$$
I have a a question about this. Why can we discard the positive root solution? The Schwarz function is supposed to be such that $S(z) = \bar{z}$ everywhere on the ellipse but the negative root solution does not satisfy this; e.g. $S(-a) \neq -a$.

Comment: I am not familiar with the Schwarz function, and searching online has turned up no information matching what you describe here. But I will suggest that it probably needs to be a *function*, and therefore cannot have two values. That is, you can't have a Schwarz function for the entire ellipse, only for half of it at a time.

Answer (score 0):

As you say, the Schwarz function is supposed to be such that $S(z)=\bar{z}$ everywhere on the ellipse, and in the example you give $S(-a)\neq -a$.
The solution seems to be that we must choose the negative root if Re$(z)\geq 0$ and the positive root otherwise.